# sqlite select: grouping in one line, 12 entries

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with fields: 
`Client_ID, Date, Value`
where there is an entry for each of the 12 months of a year (i.e., 12 entries for each client).

I would like to create a table with just one row per Client_ID that contains all the values from each months. Something like:

`Client_ID, Date_January, Value_January, Date_February, Value_February, ........, Date_December, Value_December`

Can anyone help me with the query?

This is what I'm trying to do (not working...):

```
select
    Client_Id,
    case when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '01')) then 
        Date as Date_January,
        Value as Value_January,
    else null end
    case when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '01')) then 
        Date as Date_February,
        Value as Value_February,
    else null end
....

from Test_Table
where
    strftime('%Y', Date) = '2013'
```

;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to untangle your case constructs as they generate a single value. Use:

```
case
    when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '01')) then Date
    else null
end as Date_January,
case when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '01')) then Value
    else null
end as Value_January,
```

Then, if you want one row per client, use GROUP BY ClientID.

The third issue is how to aggregate all the Date_January columns into one row. If you really know that there is exactly one row per month per client, you can use MAX() knowing that the not null value will be higher than the NULL values:

```
select
    Client_Id,
MAX(case
    when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '01')) then Date
    else null
end) as Date_January,
MAX(case when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '01')) then Value
    else null
end) as Value_January,
MAX(case
    when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '02')) then Date
    else null
end) as Date_February,
MAX(case when ((strftime('%m', Date) = '02')) then Value
    else null
end) as Value_February,
....

from Test_Table
where
    strftime('%Y', Date) = '2013'   
group by Client_Id;
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it is working using cases like you said. Would it be possible to accomplish the same thing in a ´cleaner´ way (using for example unions or joins?)

Comment: I guess it might be a bit cleaner if you create 12 tables with different column names and union them. -- what you really would need is PIVOT http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx but for sqlite I am unaware of simple implementation of that.